# Sum of a column ignoring " - " mark

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to generate a report that looks like this:

[image]

I used the following formula to get the age analysis totals.

```
if {Table.drange} = "1-30" then
    totext({Table.balance})
else
    totext("-")
```

Since I converted the number into a string with the formula, I can't get the sum at the bottom of the report. How can i display "-" instead of zero values, but still get a total value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your formula back to this:

```
if {Table.drange}="1-30" then
  {Table.balance}
else
  0
```

Then right click the formula and select *Format Field*. Under the number tab, select *Customize*. You can then total this column as you desire